# How to set direction to MT518 swift message model object in Prowide Core (WIFE)

Tags: java, swift-mt

How to set direction to MT518 swift message model object in Prowide Core (WIFE).
Direction indicates in message application header block(block2).
eg.
{2:O5181013160718MOTIITMMAXXX00000000101607181013N}

I want to set direction to following swift mt object.

```
MT518 m = new MT518()
```

but there is no `setDirection()` api method available in MT518 model type.
`setDirection()` method available in `AbstractSwiftMessage` type object, but there is no relationship between that class and `MT518` class in the library.

link to api http://api.prowidesoftware.com/core/

Can anybody familiar with Prowide Core (WIFE) library solve this.

Answer (score 2):

By default messages created with the MTnnn classes are outgoing (input to SWIFT network). But you can always set the block 2 manually. Check out the following example and replace **SwiftBlock2Input** by **SwiftBlock2Output**

This will initialize all blocks, and inparticular for block 2 it will create a SwiftBlock2Input:

```
MT518 mt = new MT518();
```

To override the block 2 with you can just do something like this:

```
//create an instance of SwiftBlock2Output 
SwiftBlock2Output b2 = new SwiftBlock2Output();

//fill all required data for the block (notice it will be empty)
b2.setMessageType("518");
(...)

//overwrite the block in the mt object
mt.getSwiftMessage().setBlock2(b2);
```